# Getting mutter debug logs

Tags: logging, debugging, mutter

Mutter has these debug topics:

```
  META_DEBUG_FOCUS           = 1 << 0,
  META_DEBUG_WORKAREA        = 1 << 1,
  META_DEBUG_STACK           = 1 << 2,
  META_DEBUG_SM              = 1 << 3,
  META_DEBUG_EVENTS          = 1 << 4,
  META_DEBUG_WINDOW_STATE    = 1 << 5,
  META_DEBUG_WINDOW_OPS      = 1 << 6,
  META_DEBUG_GEOMETRY        = 1 << 7,
  META_DEBUG_PLACEMENT       = 1 << 8,
  META_DEBUG_PING            = 1 << 9,
  META_DEBUG_KEYBINDINGS     = 1 << 10,
  META_DEBUG_SYNC            = 1 << 11,
  META_DEBUG_STARTUP         = 1 << 12,
  META_DEBUG_PREFS           = 1 << 13,
  META_DEBUG_GROUPS          = 1 << 14,
  META_DEBUG_RESIZING        = 1 << 15,
  META_DEBUG_SHAPES          = 1 << 16,
  META_DEBUG_EDGE_RESISTANCE = 1 << 17,
  META_DEBUG_DBUS            = 1 << 18,
  META_DEBUG_INPUT           = 1 << 19,
  META_DEBUG_WAYLAND         = 1 << 20,
  META_DEBUG_KMS             = 1 << 21,
  META_DEBUG_SCREEN_CAST     = 1 << 22,
  META_DEBUG_REMOTE_DESKTOP  = 1 << 23,
  META_DEBUG_BACKEND         = 1 << 24,
  META_DEBUG_RENDER          = 1 << 25,
  META_DEBUG_COLOR           = 1 << 26,
```

I run mutter stand alone, as `mutter --wayland foot`

But whatever I set these vars to:

```
MUTTER_VERBOSE
MUTTER_DEBUG
MUTTER_USE_LOGFILE
```

...I cannot get verbose messages out of mutter.

How can I trigger all debug output, and where can I see it?

My `/tmp/mutter-PID-debug-log-*` files contains very little output, typically even zero bytes.

I also tried `MUTTER_DEBUG=all` and nothing on journal, or in the log file?

NOTE: I verified that mutter was built with `-DWITH_VERBOSE_MODE` flag, and I also verified that the debug messages show up as strings in the shared library,.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `MUTTER_DEBUG=all` will put debug messages on mutter's `stderr` stream.

The reason I was not seeing them, is because I launch on a virtual console and the console does not scroll while the screen is in graphical mode.

That caused all the debug messages to be printed over each other, for me, on the last line.

Clearing the virtual console caused the first messages to show up, and redirecting them to file gave me access to all of them.